# google maps markers

Tags: google-maps

How do do i add them to my google map ? I've added the marker manager

```
<script src="http://gmaps-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markermanager/release/src/markermanager.js"></script>
```

And used the same syntax as in the documentation but they don't show up. The coordinates are correct . Can someone please dumb it down for me . Also does the zoom level have to be to a specific value for me to see them ?

For anyone else in trouble

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Andrei,

I found the Google Android MapView tutorial to be very helpful:

```
  http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html
```

It covers creating a basic map application, as well as adding overlays to the MapView, and links to the directions for obtaining the necessary API key.  Unfortunately (like a lot of Google's example code, apparently), there are a couple errors in the directions, but I was able to fix those fairly easily.

For example, the definition of your Overlay Class should be:

```
public class HelloItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>
```

Which not precisely what the directions say.  Eclipse turns out to be very helpful in fixing the problems with this, though.

As to your question about zoom level, it has been my experience that all of your overlays will be displayed as long is your zoom level (or pan state) allows it.  If you push them off the screen, they're not displayed, obviously, but not lost either.

R.

Comment: I'll look into the guide right away, I just wanted to point out that the V3 API does not require the API key  

    Note: This version of the Google Maps JavaScript API no longer needs API keys!

Comment: Found the answer . The problem was that i was not adding the marker at the same time when i initiated them map.